# Can I manufacture and sell the product shown in US 2010/0180382?

Tags: patent-infringement

I would like to manufacture and resell this product. What steps would I have to take considering it has a patent? Would changing the size of the product make it okay or adding a strap to the product make it okay?

In reference to the patent: [US20100180382](https://www.google.com/patents/US20100180382)

Answer (score 2):

The document you linked is a US patent application, not a patent. To check its status, you can use the site [US Public Pair](https://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair). Get past the CAPTCHA and then enter 20100180382 and select "Publication Number". When I did this I found the status as: "Abandoned -- Failure to Respond to an Office Action".

What this means, is that this particular application is unlikely to be problem with respect to manufacturing and selling your project. This doesn't mean you are home free however. It could be there are other relevant patents. I recommend you carefully read the communications listed in the "Image File Wrapper" tab in the US Public Pair site for this document. It will contain the communications between the filer and the patent office. In particular look at the "List of references cited by examiner" which should list relevant patents found by the examiner. It is also useful to read the Non-Final and Final Rejection documents and responses. Ultimately, you may find it useful to have a patent attorney or agent do a freedom-to-operate assessment.